# while setting upstart in application giving error

Tags: server, upstart, 8.04

wht i have done is

```
sudo emacs /etc/init/app.conf
```

and then i write the code for my upstart

```
# application Server

description "applicationServer"
author      "Rahul Mehta <rahul23134654@gmail.com"

start on (net-device-up
    and local-filesystems
    and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

exec /lily/bin/launch-hadoop
```

when i try to save this file it says :

```
/etc/init/: no such directory
```

what should i need to do to solve this problem.

Using Ubuntu 8.04.

On Ubuntu 11.04 it is giving me this error

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 8.04 includes an older version of Upstart that stored its configuration files in `/etc/event.d`.  So you should either put your configuration file in that directory, or upgrade to a more recent version of Ubuntu that stores Upstart configuration files in `/etc/init`.

Comment: will i will be able to do `sudo start app` if put my app.conf file in /etc/event.d/,  i tried it says `start: Unknown job: app`

Comment: I don't think the old version of Upstart had the convention of ending job configuration files in `.conf`.  You might need to use `start app.conf` with that version.  But again, you'll probably have an easier time using a newer version of Ubuntu (e.g. the 10.04 LTS release), since more of the documentation you find online will be relevant.

Comment: on ubutnu 11.04 it is giving me `start: Job failed to start` why ?